# What is the "ism" in which people are respected/entertained on the basis of people whom you know

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

What is the contemporary "ism" in which people are respected on the basis of people whom you know. The meaning is suppose if I (Jim) know some one (Jack) and he (Jack) introduces me to John. Then only John will entertain me for any of social or business deals. Else if i approach John directly he will discriminate me over whom Jack and people like jack whom John knows. In other words, John would be entertaining people whom he knows thru Jack and alike.

PS: Discriminat-ism on the basis of people whom you know or don't.

Comment: Are you saying that John will only deal with you because Jack introduced you, and he wouldn't do that if you approached him yourself, and you want a word for... what? John's attitude? (Hint: with this sort of question, it's far better to choose "me" and two very different names, not three very similar names.)

Comment: Yes. It is John's peculiar attitude of dealing only with Jack's acquaintance of maintaining exclusivity which reflects in an entire society which is why i am looking for an "ism"(and the same goes with Jack too - he would reciprocate the same way as john)

Comment: What do you mean by 'entertain'? 'Put on a show for'? I'm not sure I understand even with the explanation. Also 'ism' is usually for government philosophies, not personalities. Are you talking about (the concept of) celebrity? Or hiring you family and friends as in cronyism or nepotism?

Comment: @Mitch"entertain" here would mean "Take someone's request into consideration" and I am talking here of social phenomenon. cronyism is closest i can get but can it be used on larger scale such a cronyis-tic society.

Comment: @AMN 'entertain' in that usage takes as direct object the idea that is being considered, not people who are doing the consideration. Eg "The judge entertained the idea that the prosecution and defense were conspiring to get a mistrial".

Comment: Also, are you looking for a counterpart to meritocracy, where people rise in prominence based on their skills rather than who they know?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few that *could* involve who one knows - **exclusivism, cronyism, or favoritism**. All of these *can or do* discriminate on the basis of "who" one knows. The "who" or "why" may differ with each circumstance.

Your example suggests that the only way to get an appointment (my interpretation of "entertain") with "John" is through the proper chain of referral (friends/acquaintances).  That would make "**cronyism**" the best choice. It is favoritism for friends (acquaintances) without respect for qualification of others.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cronyism

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/exclusivism

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/favoritism